# Can I redirect a user to a Google Drive PDF while keeping my URL in the address bar?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

If I have a user follow a link to my site such as

```
mydomain.com/pdf/google_token
```

is there a way for me to redirect them to the Google pdf

```
drive.google.com/file/d/google_token/view
```

while keeping

```
mydomain.com/pdf/google_token
```

in the address bar?

Right now I am redirecting to google successfully using

```
RewriteRule ^pdf/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ https://drive.google.com/file/d/$1/view
```

in my .htaccess file, but it is replacing the URL with

```
drive.google.com/file/d/google_token/view
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not looking for a way to redirect. A redirection *always* changes the URL in the client, that is the whole purpose of a redirection. What you are looking for is a proxy solution, maybe in conbination with an internal rewrite. That creates a kind of mapping: the content published on that google resource is re-published through your http host.

This would be an example for such setup:

```
ProxyPass /google-drive/ https://drive.google.com/
ProxyPassReverse /google-drive/ https://drive.google.com/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?pdf/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /google-drive/file/d/$1/view [END]
```

An alternative would be to only re-publish a section of that remote resource:

```
ProxyPass /google-drive/ https://drive.google.com/file/d/
ProxyPassReverse /google-drive/ https://drive.google.com/file/d/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?pdf/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /google-drive/$1/view [END]
```

That set will work likewise in the http servers host configuration and you probably can also get it to work using a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file). If you really need to use such a file then take care that its interpretation is enabled in the host configiration. And you definitely need to have apache's proxy module loaded. You should prefer to place such rule in the http servers host configuration though, for various reasons.

If that setup is not possible, for example because you do not have access to the proxy module, then you can implement a simple routing solution which fetches the PDF in background using for example php's `cURL` extension and forwarding the payload along with correct http headers to the client that sent a request to that PDF. That is usually done for resources kept locally but there is no reason why you can't do that with remote resources too.

Some additional notes:

- if you only deliver documents form that google drive resource, then you probably do not need the `ProxyPassReverse` directive, but only the `ProxyPass`.
- if you run into a server internal error (http status 500) using the above setup then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will find a hint on an unsupported `END` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. Try using the `[L]` flag in that case, it *probably* will work the same here, but that depends on the rest of your setup.